# Trying to make a dictionary from a list retrieved from a request.get

Tags: python

So essentially, I'm having some issues trying to create a dictionary where I can after changing a request into text. I have tried to use the json parser, and urllib, but unfortunately that completely blocked so I can't use that method for to build the dictionary which leaves me with only pulling it via a request. The return I get when I use request.get and turn it into a text returns an output such as the ones listed below

```
    u'[{"name":"File Name 1","year":2012,"id":991,"distance":0}]'
    u'[{"name":"File Name 2: etc","year":2002,"id":773,"distance":0}]'
```

Originally I was using this to split it to make my dictionary before pulling elements out such as shown below.

```
    result = dict([x.split(':') for x in html.text[2:-2].split(',')])
```

The issue I'm hitting is while this split works for the first one, it certainly doesn't work for the second one since it'll cause a error based on the : in the name section. I'm just wondering what work around I can do for this case since I do have a good number of names that have a : within them, whether using another method or relying on regular expressions. Thanks again.

Comment: No... please don't butcher strings in the name of parsing... this looks like JSON, so just load it using a JSON parser. `import json; json.loads(html.text)`

Comment: You don't need to invent your own parser. Whatever went wrong with json, urllib, etc, can be fixed.

Comment: Or if you are using the `requests` library just `response.json()`.

Comment: Ah, indeed you're right. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , I manage to get the json.loads(html.text) to work and then just pull the information from that. It just didn't seem to work when I either used json and urllib or response.json() which led me to attempt to create my own parser. Thanks again.